How to export opentelemetry collector to Azure Application Insigths
I have tried this:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  azuremonitor:
    instrumentation_key: "<Your_Instrumentation_Key>"

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [azuremonitor]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: debug

Docker run:

OpenTelemetryTest % docker run -p 4317:4317 -p 4318:4318 --rm -v
/Users/locdaile/Desktop/collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml
otel/opentelemetry-collector

When I run the docker with this configuration I get this error:

error decoding 'exporters': unknown type: "azuremonitor" for id: "azuremonitor" (valid values: [otlphttp opencensus prometheus
prometheusremotewrite zipkin debug logging nop otlp file kafka])

So I'm a little loss on how to export to Azure Application Insights.

Use opencensus exporter instead of azuremonitor. Specify endpoint as the Azure Application Insights ingestion endpoint (https://dc.applicationinsights.azure.com/v2/track) and provide Application Insights instrumentation key as access_token.

can you please tell us that what framework you are using.

@SureshChikkam I'm not quite sure what you mean by which framework. I'm trying to follow guiides from https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/net/exporters/. My application is .NET framework

You must use opentelemetry-collector-contrib, the contrib version includes 3rd party exporters.
docker run -v ..../config.yml:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml -p 4318:4318 otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib

Okay, that worked, but nothing is send to Application Insights...
